How to make datapacks work over multiverse worlds
I have a datapack that I want to work over multiple worlds that i made through multiverse.
But the multiverse world don't have a datapack folder.
What do I do?
My server runs on paper 1.20.1

What's multiverse? Is that a Bukkit plugin?

@aytimothy Yes, it's a plugin. https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/multiverse-core

Per-world data packs are not supported by Multiverse due to limitations in The way custom dimensions are handled by Spigot and Bukkit.
You'll need to create a separate server and connect it using Bungiecord.
Even data packs applied to the base overworld can exhibit weird behaviours when in or referencing a multiverse world.
Related: https://github.com/Multiverse/Multiverse-Core/issues/1842
See also: https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/husksync-1-17-1-21-sync-inventories-e-chests-x-server-advancements-map-art-stats-backups.97144/
